# How to keep track of the entity id for the stuff that was just added to the db?

Tags: clojure, datomic

On a html-post page a user can input various fields and hit submit,

My router.clj code looks like

```
 (POST "/postGO" [ post-title post-input post-tags :as request ]
    (def email (get-in request [:session :ze-auth-email]))
      ;; connect to datomic and write in the request
    (dbm/add-ze-post post-title post-input post-tags email) ;; db insert

    {:status 200, 
     :body "successfully added the post to the database", 
     :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}}) ;;generic return page
```

It works well, but I want to redirect the user afterwards to a page that can show them their uploaded post.  To do this, it would be very helpful to have the eid of the entity just transacted.

```
;; code from my dbm file for playing directly with the database
;; id est: the db transact code
(defn add-ze-blurb [title, content, tags, useremail]
  (d/transact conn [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user),
                     :post/title title,
                     :post/content content,
                     :post/tag tags,
                     :author/email useremail}]))
```

Is there any way to have datomic return the eid as soon as something is added to the DB successfully, or should I use another query right afterward to make sure it's there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple cases, simply deref the future returned by `d/transact` and use `:tx-data`. Full example:

```
(require '[datomic.api :refer [db q] :as d])
(def uri "datomic:mem://test")
(d/create-database uri)

(def conn (d/connect uri))
(def schema [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/db)
              :db/ident :foo
              :db/valueType :db.type/string
              :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
              :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}])
@(d/transact conn schema)

(def tempid (d/tempid :db.part/user))
(def tx [{:db/id tempid :foo "bar"}])
(def result @(d/transact conn tx)) ;; 
(def eid (:e (second (:tx-data result))))
(assert (= "bar" (:foo (d/entity (db conn) eid))))
```

You can alternatively use `d/resolve-tempid`:

```
(def eid (d/resolve-tempid (db conn) (:tempids result) tempid))
(assert (= "bar" (:foo (d/entity (db conn) eid))))
```

As described in the [Datomic documentation](http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html#processing-transactions), after the deref the transaction will have been applied by the transactor and the data returned reflects the new value of the database.